# changing fontstyle in a epubfile increase/decrease the pagecount in uiwebview

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, xhtml

I am Developing an app epubReeader .I have used css to change the font style in UIWebView and font size is fixed for all font styles .But the problem is when I am changing the font style of the font in webview ,the number of pages are  either increased or decreased depends on the font style.How can I fix the  total no of pages,  After changing the font style.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Revise your prompt so that you can be properly helped. Furthermore, if would be helpful if you could supply the relevant CSS so we could see where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

I have an educated guess. The fonts that you use will have to have the same or very similar characteristics such as letter spacing, letter size etc. Otherwise, every time you change the font, the layout will change which in turn causes your page numbers to change.

Comment: thanks for reply @Vimal i used fixed font size for all styles.And what about letter spacing i have to check it .do you have any idea to fix the letter spacing for all font styles.....

Comment: Santosh, I think you'll have to specify the letter spacing for individual fonts. Might be easier to find fonts that have similar attributes and offer them instead of all fonts.